# Can I say that if a set is open then it does not contain its limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We say that a set of real numbers is closed if and only if it contains its limit points. Can I say that since a set of real numbers is open, it does not contain its limit points.

Comment: Open does not imply not closed, e.g. $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: This is not true, consider the interval $[0,1)$, it no contains $1$ (a limit point) and it is not open

Comment: Nope.  Can't say that at all.  1) Open does not mean "not closed" (and vice versa) and 2) Not containing all the limit points does not mean not containing *any* limit points.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb R$  It is open and contains all it's limit points.  Consider $\{0,1,2,3\}$ it is closed.  It does not have *any* limit points.  And it doesn't contain any of its limit points (cause there are none).  And consider $(0,1)$; its limit points are $0$ and $1$ *AND* ***EVERY*** point in between.  $(0,1)$ is open it it contains many (but not all) of its limit points.

Comment: It's true with the *boundary* points instead of limit points, i.e. the common limit points with the complement of the set.

Comment: @Berci so an open set doesn't contain any of its boundary points.  True, but we should keep in mind an open set, and a closed set need not *have* any boundary points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

To begin with OPEN does not mean not CLOSED and CLOSED does not mean not OPEN.  Consider $\emptyset$ is both closed and open.  So is $\mathbb R$.  And consider $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

Second; closed means contains *all* its limit points if it has any. But if it also means that if a set doesn't have *any* limit points then it is also closed.  This is because there are no limit points so that the set isn't *missing* any limit points; it has them all.  So for example:  $\{0,1,5\}$ is closed because it has no limit points so no limit point is outside the set.

And an open set may have limit points that are inside it.  Consider $(0,1)$ then point $\frac 12$ is a limit point because every neighborhood of $\frac 12$ has a point (other then $\frac 12$) that is in $(0,1)$. So $A$ has *some* of its limit points (but not all-- it is missing $0$ and $1$.

But an ope set doesn't need to be missing any of it's limit points.  $\mathbb R$ is open and it contains *all* its limit points.  In this case $\mathbb R$ is both open *and* closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, $O$ is open iff $O^c$ is closed, so iff $O^c$ contains all its limit points. Or equivalently, $O$ does not contain a limit point of its complement.